# Is there any way to call state class in state class?

Tags: flutter, dart, state, setstate

main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'A',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Bookman',
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'A'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
  //navigationBar createNavState() => navigationBar();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        endDrawer: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [],
          ),
        ),
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(SizeConfig.screenHeight / 16),
          child: AppBar(
            leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
            title: new Text(
              'A',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
            ),
            actions: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                child: Icon(Icons.search),
              ),
              Icon(Icons.person),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
                  height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * (1 / 16),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[200])),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: SizeConfig.screenWidth / 7,
                      height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * (13 / 16),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[200])),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [Container(child: Text("CALL IN HERE!") )],
                    ),
                    Row(children: [
                      Container(
                        width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * (6 / 7),
                        height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * (1 / 16),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[200])),
                      )
                    ]),
                    Row(
                      children: [myDataTable()],
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ));
  }


}
```

navigationBar.dart

```
var _logo = new Image.asset('image/**.ico', width: 40, height: 50);

Future dwln() async {
  const url = "https://**/download.php";
  if (await canLaunch(url))
    await launch(url);
  else
    
    throw "Could not launch $url";
}

//class navigationBar extends StatefulWidget {}

class navigationBarState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * (6 / 7),
      height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * (1 / 16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[200])),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "New   ",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                  onPressed: () {
                    which = "new";
                    endDrawer();
                  },
                  iconSize: 15,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Exit grid view   ",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedUsers.length = 0;
                      if (getir == true) {
                        getir = false;
                      } else {
                        getir = true;
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  iconSize: 15,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Export to EXCEL    ",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.save),
                  color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                  onPressed: () {
                    dwln();
                  },
                  iconSize: 15,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Import EXCEL file   ",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.import_contacts),
                  color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  iconSize: 15,
                ),
                if (editlabel == true)
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Edit   ",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            which = "update";
                          });

                          endDrawer();
                        },
                        iconSize: 15,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hi everyone,
I want to call navigationBarState class in main.dart file. But because of the "state", it doesn't allow to do that. It says "The argument type 'navigationBarState' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.". But I need State extend for using setState. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have *only* the state. You need a `StatefulWidget`, too. I'm not sure why you commented it out, but you need to put it back in.

At the very least you will need:

```
class navigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  navigationBar ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  navigationBarState createState() => navigationBarState();
}
```

And then you can put a `navigationBar` in your widget tree, not the state itself.

The state class itself must use the widget as it's generic parameter:

```
class navigationBarState extends State<navigationBar>
```